# Roll 10 fair die. What is the probability that the number 1 appears exactly four times, on four consecutive rolls

Tags: probability

I am asked:

> Roll $10$ fair die. What is the probability that the number $1$ appears
>   exactly four times, on four consecutive rolls?

The answer I was given is
$$\frac{1}{6^{10}}\cdot7\cdot5^6$$
with a comment saying we multiply by 7 "for the first roll".

However, this doesn't make sense to me since there are only $6$ possible sides to the die. So it's not counting sides of the die.

The only reason I can come up with for the 7 appearing is the case when the first $6$ rolls do not produce a sequence of consecutive $1$'s, so the $7$th item must begin the sequence of consecutive $1$'s

So where exactly is this $7$ coming from?

Comment: "for the first roll" refers to the position (out of the ten) of the first roll which is a 1. Only 7 positions for the first 1 are possible: position one through seven.

Comment: Do you mean "Roll 10 fair dice", or "Roll a fair die 10 times"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a better understanding, the seven alternative cases are:

```
 [1 1 1 1] * * * * * *
 * [1 1 1 1] * * * * *
 * * [1 1 1 1] * * * *
 * * * [1 1 1 1] * * *
 * * * * [1 1 1 1] * *
 * * * * * [1 1 1 1] *
 * * * * * * [1 1 1 1]
```

The six stars are $2,3,4,5,6$ (five categories) and can take $5^6$ combinations. Hence the numerator is $(7)5^6$. The total number of combinations is $6^{10}$.

Comment: This was really helpful for visualizing the problem.

Comment: So you could say that the four consecutive "1" are one single contagious unit and together with the 6 other free spaces that makes 7 permutable objects in total?

Comment: Yes @QBrute, you can think of the sequence as a "unique" element among $6$ other elements.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a shifting window where you record the beginning position of consecutive $1$.

It can start from position $1$ to $7$.

Starting from position $1$ means roll $1$ to roll $4$ are  $1$'s, the rest are not.

Starting from position $7$ means roll $7 $ to roll $10$ are $1$'s, the rest are not.